# A small display bug in the reputation graphics in Edge browser only

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, reputation-graph, microsoft-edge

My reputation graphic show the diagram below.

I think the year columns 2016-2019 are not displayed well. Is this a (small) bug?

I'm using Microsoft Edge:

```
Microsoft Edge 44.17763.771.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763
(C) 2018 Microsoft
```

Windows version:

```
Windows 10 Enterprise
version 1809
```

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me (Firefox on Android): https://i.imgur.com/LxH8EBM.jpg What browser are you using? What version? What operating system?

Comment: Also fine in Chrome-based Android browser and Chrome on a desktop. I think this is a bug in your browser or glitch in something else.

Comment: @Mokubai I'm using my work laptop now (where I cannot install other browsers), but I will try at home later. I added the version in my question.

Comment: I can replicate the display issue in Edge as well. Windows 10 1909.

Comment: @MichaelFrank About same here (version 1809).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the page is using the CSS property `justify-content: space evenly;`, which according to MDN is currently in Working Draft spec, and is not supported by IE or Edge.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: @MichaelFrank I asked a moderator to change it (which has been done), thanks.